# Efficient way to write to file in random order

Tags: c#, file, c#-4.0

I'm having some difficulties in designing an app.

My app is receiving about 10 million external records each day. The records are deleted after 24 hours.

Those records are coming from external system which I have no control over.  I cannot use a database for tech reasons.

So I'm going to work with files.
The first file is a binary file that saves the data.
The second one has the record number, the position to the binary file, and the record's length.

So the thing is that the records are coming in a random order meaning I can get 1....100 and then 216....
So I need to write in the file between 100 and 216 the index plus -1 -1.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Could you clarify the last part? I cant understand what you mean by "So i need to write in the file between 100 and 216 the index plus -1 -1."

Comment: Yeah sure.Say i receive 100 records identified by sequence number 1 to 100. After receiving the 100 record i received the seqyence from 216 record. So there is a black between 100 to 216 that i need to fill. For example : 101 -1 -1

Comment: If you can write into a file anyway, you can write into sqlite (no db server required).

Comment: Its still an issue. Its an orgnization and we dont have licesnce for it. So i cant use it..only files

Comment: Sqlite is public domain, and can be used without a license. Unfortunately you clarification doesnt help me, it does not provide any additional information. It might just be me, but maybe a more visual clarification could help? Why do you need to "fill" the hole? With what? Are you asking how to iterate between the number 100 and 216?

Comment: Im receiving data that is stored in a binary file. The data is records i receive from external ststem. When i add the data to the file i save another file that contains the record number sequence number, position in the binary file and its length. But the record seq number is random there for if id like to know if record number 213 arrived i need to fill out the spaces between those records number

Comment: Still unclear, can you illustrate in simple ASCII art or image what you're trying to do, what is the end result you want, plus how will the file going to be used afterwards? Also you need to mention with @ whoever you're talking to because otherwise we don't get any notification.